# Relationship between mathematics and music

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I have a strong mathematical background and I am interested in the relationship between mathematics and music. I have found some introductory material on the web. Do you know any good books that will broaden my perspective of this subject?

Comment: Great question!  See my profile to realize just how interesting I find this! +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an amateur pianist and math enthusiast, I really enjoyed [*Music: A Mathematical Offering*](http://www.amazon.it/Music-Mathematical-Offering-Dave-Benson/dp/0521619998), by Dave Benson: is not comprehensive, but it *does* contain a *really* awesome overview of the subject of sound and music and their relationship with mathematics.

Comment: I could find it on the web. It seems really interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Godel Escher Bach - a great book that stresses the connection between math, art, music, and logic. I highly recommend it.

Comment: I have already read it. It was fun anyway.